# Dealing with Exceptions and Errors where errors are OK

Tags: java, json, exception

I have a JSON string into which I'm adding multiple variables. The problem here is that sometimes not all the data will have something entered, and therefore return a NullPointerException.

For example, here's some code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException  {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("att1", val1);
    obj.put("att2", val2);
    obj.put("att3", val3);
    obj.put("att4", val4);
    obj.put("att5", val5);
    obj.put("att6", val6);

    System.out.println(obj.toString());

}
```

This will work, because I'm throwing an exception. However, say one time I run it, and val4 doesn't exist, I'll get a JSONException and my whole code will stop. What I really want is for the code to say "OK, nothing by the name of val4, so let's ignore it and move to the next line of code.

The methods I know of are using successive if statements (for each attribute I check if it's null before trying to add it) or using multiple try/catches.

I know ignoring errors is a massive taboo, so instead of saying *I was wondering if there was a method of ignoring the error and just continuing with the next line of code*, **is there a good way to check each individual line before entering it and if there is a null value, ignore the line before carrying on?**

(although, I would be happy to ignore errors on this one block of code)

Cheers and TIA,
Kesh

Comment: If val4 is null do you still want to add attr4 to JSONObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you only want to add the pair if the value is not null. `JSONObject#putOpt` does just this.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#putOpt(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: Oh dear, how did I not see that? Thanks a lot, Matt! Appreciated it.

Comment: Do you know if there's a get version for this?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the JSONObject documentation. All the methods that start with "opt" try to return something sensible if there is no mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in ignoring the exception and continue populating the `JSONObject` you can have your values ready in a Map and use a loop like this (while ignoring any `JSONException`s that may get thrown)

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : valMap.entrySet()) {
    try {
        jsonObj.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); // attr4, null
    } catch (JSONException ignored) {}
}
```

Which data structure you use would depend on how you've stored (or are getting the `vals`) but I hope you get the idea. You should also then remove the `throws JSONException` in your method declaration.